# how to use CSS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show a cursor not allowed option on a button. 
I want to do this with using CSS in javascript when my if-condition is met.

My button code is like this:

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-success" title=""></button>
```

this is my if condition:

```
if (percent <= 99) 
{
//using class name:
document.getElementsByClassName("btn").style.cursor = "not-allowed";

}
else 
{
//using id:  
document.getElementsById("mybtn").style.cursor = "allowed";

}
```

Comment: can anyone help me out, how should i use css for button  in javascript.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns collection hence you are suppose to use `loop` or if you are targeting first element then `[0]` over `getElementsByClassName` and then apply style.. `getElementsById` should work fine.. Correct the typo, it is `getElementById`, it is singular as IDs are always unique..

Comment: For myBtn only:

     `myBtn.style.cursor =  percent <=99 ? 'not-allowed' : 'default';`

Comment: its not working, i have corrected code to document.getElementById("myBtn").style.cursor = "not-allowed";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes according to your question what @Rayon said is absolutely correct. You have to use loop in your case as it returns a collection of objects.

If you don't want to use loops and still want to achieve this, Then the ultimate solution is to use JQuery Library. Using Jquery library you can do like this.

```
if (percent <= 99) { $(".btn").css("cursor", "not-allowed");}
else {$("#mybtn").css("cursor", "allowed");}
```

this will apply to all the elements with in the page.

Comment: Javascript, not jQuery

Comment: I think you should first read the answer before commenting. I have already accepted in my reply that this is not the solution as per your requirement which means I am giving suggestion to Mr. Deb that there is another option for achieving this.

Comment: I read your answer. I didn't see anything written like that. Again the question was to use CSS in Javascript. And also using jquery is not the Ultimate Solution. Peace :)

Answer (score 0):

cursor style property does not have **allowed**. Instead you can use **default**.

```
if (percent <= 99) 
{
//using class name:
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].style.cursor = "not-allowed";
//or using id
document.getElementsById("btn").style.cursor = "not-allowed";
}
else 
{
//using class name:
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].style.cursor = "default";
//or using id
document.getElementsById("btn").style.cursor = "default";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code in native Javascript to help you get started.

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

buttons.forEach(button => {
  percent <= 99 ? (button.style.cursor = "not-allowed") : (button.style.cursor = "allowed");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont think why its not working, but we can done it by adding a class 
your style class should be:

```
.btn-disable
  {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    opacity: .65;
  }

if (percent <= 99) 
{
//using class name:
document.getElementsByClassName("btn").className += " btn-disable";
}
else 
{
//using id:  
document.getElementById("myBtn").classList.remove("btn-disable");

}
```